# Removing CoreData migrations used in development

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

We developing a iOS app that uses CoreData.  To keep ourselves from going crazy and having to delete the app every time we make a change to the models, we have been using lightweight migrations.  At this point we have about 30 or so migrations and are getting ready to submit for review.

Looking at the .ipa file it looks like all of these migrations exist in there as separate files.  I was wondering if there is any easy way to collapse all of these migrations into a single model file now that we are done with development and ready to ship 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague of mine figured it out so I thought I would share it here.

1. Open the project and right click on the .xcdatamodeld, and delete it (just the references) from the project
2. Open the finder and find the .xcdatamodel, right click on it and show contents of package
3. Delete all of the migrations that you don't need
4. Go back into Xcode and add in the root .xcdatamodeld into your project
5. Test
6. Commit your changes

Done.

Anyone doing this I would highly recommend making a backup (or using version control such as git) to protect yourself against inadvertent mistakes.

I am sure glad not to have to ship 30 odd dev migrations to our 1.0 customer!!!